# Magento: retrieving products via phtml

Tags: magento, php

I am trying to call a list of products with names, images, etc.. from a specific category in a template using php.

It seems like this should be easy to do, but I have been working on this for hours and haven't made any progress. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what "phtml" is? Do you mean PHP? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Are you trying to display random products, newly added ..etc? Are you trying to add it from a cms page, layout.xml ..etc?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'm trying to display product information from a specific category using php.

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

Comment: Is there a way to do this in php not xml

Comment: What page are you trying to add the products to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your magento phtml file add

```
<?php 
     $category_id = xx;
     echo $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
                ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')
                ->setCategoryId($category_id)
                ->toHtml();
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this doesn't output anything when I try it.

Comment: This worked! Are there any good resources for understanding Magento better?